# Not work JavaScript function delete

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript where I get data from a DataBase for my shopping cart. But when I want to delete  cart data  it does not work my code.
I do not know if I'm getting well into this part of the code
`javascript:deleteRow(this)`.

I leave the complete code of my two functions: `listarPedido()` and (at the bottom) `deleteRow(r)`.

```
function listarPedido(){
   var articulos = localStorage.getItem("productos");
   var productos = articulos.split(";");
    var contador = 0;//cuenta numero de articulos en el carrito

 for( var i = 0; i < productos.length - 1; i++ ){
    var item = productos[i].split(",");
    var pedido = "";

    for( var j = 0; j < item.length; j++ ){
        pedido = '<tr>'+
                '<td class="text-center">'+ '<img style="width: 100px; height: 100px" src="' + item[0] + '"/></td>' +
                '<td id="celiminar" style="text-align:left;"><b>'+ item[1].toUpperCase() + '<br><br><br><br></b>' +
                '<a style="text-decoration:none">Editar</a> | <a href="javascript:deleteRow(this)" style="text-decoration:none;">Delete</a></td>' +
                '<td style="text-align:right; color:red"><b>'+ 'S/.'+ item[2] + '</b></td>' +
                '<td class="text-center"><b>'
                + '<input type="number" name="txtcant'+i+'" id="txtcant'+i+'" min="1" max="15" value="'+ item[3] +'" class="form-control">' + 
                '</b></td>'+
                '<td style="text-align:right;"><b>'+ 'S/.'+ (item[2]*item[3]).toFixed(2) + '</b></td>';
    }
    //<a href="javascript:void()"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
    $("#detallePedido").append(pedido);  

    $("#txtcant"+i).change(function(){
        resumen();
        //al cambiar el numero actualiza el total
        $("#detallePedido tr").find("td").eq(4).html('<b>'+ 'S/.'+ (item[2] * $(this).val()).toFixed(2)+ '</b>'); 
    });

    contador++;
}

$("#lblnum").text(contador +" ARTÍCULOS");
}

 function deleteRow(r) {
      var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
      document.getElementById(".table").deleteRow(i);
  }
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: For one thing, you do `document.getElementById(".table")`, but there's no reference to that anywhere. Also, you have `<tr>` but no `</tr>` in your HTML, so that may be something. Also, see if `i` is the correct value when you run it.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is simply wrong:

```
document.getElementById(".table").deleteRow(i);
```

I doubt you have an element with the ID ".table".

Your function, rewritten to get the proper table:

```
function deleteRow(link) {
    var row = link.parentNode.parentNode;
    var idx = row.rowIndex;
    var table = row.parentNode;
    table.deleteRow(idx);
}
```

Comment: You could provide the solution here though: `r.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.deleteRow(r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);`

Comment: @somethinghere Correct. Cleaned it up and added the code.

Comment: Since you are cleaning up I would rename the argument `r` to `cell`, but thats just me :) It would line up nicely with your other variables!

Comment: (Sorry to be a pain but just realised it passes in a link and not a cell, so maybe cell is slightly confusing, but what the hell. Just wanted to point that out. Already +1-ed this though :) )

Comment: Edited again :P And no problem, it just means I wasn't paying enough attention!